# Process data in pipe in asynchronous way

Tags: rxjs

I have `process` function which works in async way - it takes line of input text and process it (in snippet below - for simplification - it extract number from line). The lines came form input large file (many GB) and are read and send to pipe one-by-one (this is 'simulated' by `of` operator below). The `process` function is slow - but reading lines is fast - so critical point is to read and process lines one-by-one to avoid memory "stack-overflow".

```js
const { of, Subject } = rxjs;
const { take, bufferCount, map, finalize } = rxjs.operators;


let source = of("line 11 of text", "line 22 of text", "line 33 of text") // large file with lines
  .pipe(map(line => process(line, ()=> { 
    // ???? how te callback/pipe shoud look ????
  }))
);

source.subscribe(x=> console.log(x)); 
// expected result shoud be: 
// 11
// 22
// 33
  

// This is third-party library - I cannot change it
function process(line, callback) {
  setTimeout(_=>{ 
    let result = line.match(/\d/)[0];
    callback(result);
  }, (1+Math.random()*9)*100); // random processing time
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I don't know how to do it - any idea?

Comment: Since you cannot change third party method so I doubt that you can handle this using rxjs. The main problem is that the third part api is not returning an observable which is not fitting in rxjs basic requirements. Also somehow we can manage rxjs way by using delay/debounce operators but again because how JS event loop works the provided solution will not be perfect. You should find a way to return observable from third party api (if you can)

Comment: @user2216584 Marcin give solution - look on it

Comment: Thanks! It’s a new learning to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your callback to Promise as Promises can work with `rxjs` streams.

```
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap } from "rxjs/operators";

const promiseWrapper = line => new Promise(resolve => process(line, resolve));

let source = of("line 11 of text", "line 22 of text", "line 33 of text").pipe(
  concatMap(item => promiseWrapper(item))
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
// expected result shoud be:
// 11
// 22
// 33

// This is third-party library - I cannot change it
function process(line, callback) {
  setTimeout(_ => {
    let result = line.match(/\d+/)[0];
    callback(result);
  }, 1000);
}
```

also, I've prepared [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-emxslb) (or below snippet)

```js
const { of, Subject } = rxjs;
const { concatMap } = rxjs.operators;

const promiseWrapper = line => new Promise(resolve => process(line, resolve));

let source = of(
  "line 11 of text", 
  "line 22 of text", 
  "line 33 of text") // large file with lines
  .pipe(concatMap(item => promiseWrapper(item))
);

source.subscribe(x=> console.log(x)); 
// expected result shoud be: 
// 11
// 22
// 33
  

// This is third-party library - I cannot change it
function process(line, callback) {
  setTimeout(_=>{ 
    let result = line.match(/\d+/)[0];
    callback(result);
  }, (1+Math.random()*9)*100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`bindCallback`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindCallback) to convert a function of type `f(x, callback)` to a function `g(x)` that returns a cold observable that emits the result passed to the callback.

```ts
import { bindCallback, of } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap } from "rxjs/operators";

const boundProcess = bindCallback(process);
let source = of("line 11 of text", "line 22 of text", "line 33 of text").pipe(
  concatMap(line => boundProcess(line))
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
// expected result shoud be:
// 11
// 22
// 33

// This is third-party library - I cannot change it
function process(line, callback) {
  setTimeout(_ => {
    let result = line.match(/\d+/)[0];
    callback(result);
  }, 1000);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2rai4c?file=index.ts